# get data from ajax in jstree

Tags: c#, asp.net

here is my code:

```
var data = "";
    $(function() {
        $("#MainTree,#SubTree").jstree({
            "json_data": {
                "data": data,
                "ajax":{
                    type: "POST",
                    async: true,
                    url: "Default.aspx/GetJson",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    //data: '{name:""}',
                    dataType: "json",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(msg) {
                         data = msg;

                    },
                    error: function(err) {
                        alert(err);
                    }
                },

            },
            "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui", "dnd"]
        });
    });
```

This is my GetJson method:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetJson()
{
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    Dictionary<string, object> row = null;

    DataTable dtEmployee = new DataTable();

    dtEmployee.Columns.Add("EmpId", typeof(int));
    dtEmployee.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    dtEmployee.Columns.Add("Address", typeof(string));
    dtEmployee.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

    //
    // Here we add five DataRows.
    //
    dtEmployee.Rows.Add(25, "Rk", "Gurgaon", DateTime.Now);
    dtEmployee.Rows.Add(50, "Sachin", "Noida", DateTime.Now);
    dtEmployee.Rows.Add(10, "Nitin", "Noida", DateTime.Now);
    dtEmployee.Rows.Add(21, "Aditya", "Meerut", DateTime.Now);
    dtEmployee.Rows.Add(100, "Mohan", "Banglore", DateTime.Now);

    foreach (DataRow dr in dtEmployee.Rows)
    {
        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (DataColumn col in dtEmployee.Columns)
        {
            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
        }
        rows.Add(row);
    }
    return serializer.Serialize(rows);
}
```

In my Default.aspx.cs, I created a method name GetJson, when I run this code, it returned alert(error). Please help me to find out what was happened?

Editted: when i check in browser,the method get status code 200 OK, but in respone..it show me the page Default.aspx(context html)

Comment: Maybe put data passed to jstree so uers can check if data is valid

Comment: Can you show the GetJson method? and bit details over the error you're receiving in response.

Comment: oh, i tried it..but variable "data" hadn't been declared in jstree.js so I can't put data passed to jstree.